# "Connection Timed Out" on Guest Machine

Tags: virtual-machines, maven

When I run "mvn install" on my guest VM box, I get multiple "Connection Timed Out" errors when searching for a file to download.

> [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:pom:1.0-alpha-5' from
>   repository maven-nexus (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public): Error transferring file: Connection timed out

Note - I've opened the file path that maven can't find to Firefox and curl. Both of them can read/download the file based on the path that maven uses and cannot find.

I need to use a proxy, but I believe it's configured correctly. For a guest VM using a proxy, is it acceptable to use the same proxy settings as the host machine?

As I understand, port forwarding is only required from host to guest, but not vice-versa.

Please advise.

**EDIT** - Turns out it was a proxy issue. I had to configure my guest machine's proxy correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is VM a Linux? If yes, try:

```
export http_proxy=http://your_proxy:port
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
mvn install
```

If this does not help, you can

- look at logs on proxy server(is there any connection attempt?)
- use packet sniffer/analyzer program like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what actually is happening

Comment: It looks like my http_proxy environment variable was wrong. Does maven use these env vars that you listed?

Comment: I don't know anything about maven, but I know that http_proxy and ftp_proxy are standard environment variables in unix to save proxy information. If this tip helped, maven uses them.

Comment: I believe that maven, a Java build tool, uses its settings.xml file, options passed in via the command line, and/or the $MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to find out, among others, what proxy to use.

Answer (score 1):

As you can download the files with Firefox and curl (inside the vm?) i'd double check proxy settings for mvn.

Comment: I'm using vagrant, if that matters.